# c++ console window won't take inputs but image window will

Tags: c++, console

I am writing a program using c++ opencv and a console window. I want to be able to have a help menu where the user can input desired threshold values. The problem I have is the inputs only work if the image window is selected and not if the console window is selected. The inputs are not in main, there in void onNewDepthSample(  as seen below. I want to get inputs when the console window is selected, they work fine when an image window is selected. A short sample of the code is below:

```
void changeItems()
{
    int input = 0;
    cout << "Welcome: Here is where to set up the proper image quality\n";
    cout << "Press 'h' for the help menu and 'x' to leave the loop\n";
    char keyInputs = 'a';

    while(keyInputs != 'x')
    {
        cin >> keyInputs;

        if( keyInputs == 'h' )
        {

            cout << "help menu\n";

        }

    }
    cout << "Leaving the loop";

    changeValues = 0;
}
void onNewDepthSample(DepthNode node, DepthNode::NewSampleReceivedData data)
{
    //printf("Z#%u: %d\n",g_dFrames,data.vertices.size());
    int p[3];
    int circleTemp[6000] ={0};
    int circleTempVal = 0;
    int resultsTotalAfterRemove = 0;
    int resultsTotalAfterRemoveVideo = 0;
    float robotx = 0;
    float roboty = 0;
    char * cCoordinates = new char[100];
    char * cDepth = new char[100];

    p[0] = CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
    p[1] = 100;
    p[2] = 0;
    int32_t w, h;
    FrameFormat_toResolution(data.captureConfiguration.frameFormat,&w,&h);
    if(changeValues != 0)
    {
        changeItems();
    }
```

Comment: If you want to read input from the console window, you have to use the console input functions. Either the standard input stream `std::cin`, or the [Windows console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The `cvWaitKey` is part of OpenCV, so of course it will only work using the OpenCV window.

Comment: Formatting the code would make it a little easier to read on here.

Comment: Thank You, I just started with opencv and didn't realize cvWaitKey only worked for cv windows.